# Python Pickle call constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, pickle, jsonpickle

I'd like to provide defaults for missing values using Python's pickle serialiser. Since the classes are simple, the defaults are naturally present in the classes's `__init__` methods.

I can see from [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle) that there is `__getnewargs__`. However, this only works for cases where `__getnewargs__` was present prior to "pickling".

Is there any way to tell python pickle to call always the constructor rather than starting with an uninitialised object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unpickling will always create an instance without calling `__init__()`.  This is by design.  In python 2 it was possible to override `__getinitargs__()` to cause unpickling to call `__init__()` with some arguments, but it was necessary to have had this method overridden at pickling time.  This is not available in python 3 anymore.

To achieve what you want, wouldn't it be enough to just manually call `self.__init__()` from `self.__setstate__(state)`?  You can provide any default arguments not found in `state`.